# Is there any opensource/free that renders a Gantt from caldav calendars?

Tags: gantt-chart, caldav

Caldav calendar can be grouped by Locations/Groups and events can have people joining them so it would be nice to use those infos for project planning, is there anyone who has already done this and/or knows how to do that in some kind of programming language in a way that I can integrate the result in a web page?